# Given $\lim a_n =a$ and $\lim b_n =b$, show $\lim\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k b_{n+1-k}=ab$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given $\lim a_n =a$ and $\lim b_n =b$,  show $\lim\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k b_{n+1-k}=ab$

As you can see, two limit are expanding in two different direction. I have no idea about how to do it.

Comment: At first glance, to me it seems similar to how one would show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n = ab$, but with more work. Do you know that proof?

Comment: I know that proof and try the similar way. But this time, I think more technique is need. Since once $a_n$ converge ,$b_n$ doesn't.